# Trying to store a command in a shell variable but it errors out

Tags: shell, amazon-iam

I have a string which will be used as command. Also before running that command I need to replace  a string pattern with a variable value..

But is upon assigning I am getting command not found for all of the output lines.

I have tried putting the escape chars but not helping.

```html
role-command="aws sts assume-role --role-arn  arn:aws:iam::<acct_id>:role/AWS-Role --role-session-name temp-aws-rolesession --output text --duration-seconds 3600 --query 'Credentials.[[join(`=`,[`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, AccessKeyId])],[join(`=`,[`AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, SecretAccessKey])],[join(`=`,[`AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`, SessionToken])]]'"
```

bash: =: command not found
bash: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: command not found
bash: =: command not found
bash: AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: command not found
bash: =: command not found
bash: AWS_SESSION_TOKEN: command not found

bash: role-command=aws sts assume-role --role-arn  arn:aws:iam::<acct_id>:role/AWS-Role --role-session-name temp-aws-rolesession --output text --duration-seconds 3600 --query 'Credentials.[[join(,[, AccessKeyId])],[join(,[, SecretAccessKey])],[join(,[, SessionToken])]]': No such file or directory

And the I was suppose to do sed -i s/<acct_id>/97476414123/g ${role-command}

How can I achieve this?

I have tried even below:

```html
role-command="aws sts assume-role --role-arn  arn:aws:iam::<acct_id>:role/AWS-Role --role-session-name temp-aws-rolesession --output text --duration-seconds 3600 --query 'Credentials.[[join(\`=\`,[\`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID\`, AccessKeyId])],[join(\`=\`,[\`AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY\`, SecretAccessKey])],[join(\`=\`,[\`AWS_SESSION_TOKEN\`, SessionToken])]]'"

Getting below:

bash: role-command=aws sts assume-role --role-arn  arn:aws:iam::<acct_id>:role/AWS-Role --role-session-name temp-aws-rolesession --output text --duration-seconds 3600 --query 'Credentials.[[join(`=`,[`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, AccessKeyId])],[join(`=`,[`AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, SecretAccessKey])],[join(`=`,[`AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`, SessionToken])]]': No such file or directory
```

Regards,
SA

Comment: I have got this right. I can confirm its done now.
............................

y="$(echo "aws sts assume-role --role-arn  arn:aws:iam::<acct_id>:role/AWS-Role --role-session-name role-session --output text --duration-seconds 3600 --query 'Credentials.[[join(\`=\`,[\`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID\`, AccessKeyId])],[join(\`=\`,[\`AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY\`, SecretAccessKey])],[join(\`=\`,[\`AWS_SESSION_TOKEN\`, SessionToken])]]'" |sed 's/<acct_id>/56787654567/g')"

Answer (score 0):

I have got this right. I can confirm its done now

```html
y="$(echo "aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::<acct_id>:role/AWS-Role --role-session-name role-session --output text --duration-seconds 3600 --query 'Credentials.[[join(`=`,[`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, AccessKeyId])],[join(`=`,[`AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, SecretAccessKey])],[join(`=`,[`AWS_SESSION_TOKEN`, SessionToken])]]'" |sed 's/<acct_id>/56787654567/g')"
```